# Writing a code for a CRC using D-FlipFlop in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm learning VHDL for a university project. The goal is to write a CRC circuit given a certain polynomial. I found online solution that uses register but I wanted to do it by using actual D-FlipFlop.

So I created the D-FlipFlop and put in my main file several instances of them using generate to be more flexible and be able to add or remove flipflop easily.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity LFSR is
    generic (NBit   : positive := 8);
    port(
        clk :in     std_logic;
        reset   :in     std_logic;
        din :in     std_logic;
        dout    :out    std_logic_vector(Nbit-1 downto 0)
        );
    end LFSR;
architecture rtl of LFSR is

    component DFC
        port(
            clk :in std_logic;
            reset   :in std_logic;
            d   :in std_logic;
            crc :out    std_logic;
            q   :out    std_logic
        );  
    end component DFC;

    signal q_s  : std_logic_vector (NBit-1 downto 0):= (others => '0');
    signal crc_t    : std_logic_vector (NBit-1 downto 0):= (others => '0'); --registro temporaneo su cui fare le operazioni

    signal int_0    :std_logic := '0';
    signal int_2    :std_logic := '0';
    signal int_4    :std_logic := '0';
    signal int_8    :std_logic := '0';




    begin 
        int_0<= din xor q_s(7);
        int_2<= q_s(1) xor q_s(7);
        int_4<= q_s(3) xor q_s(7);

        GEN: for i in 0 to Nbit-1 generate

            FIRST:  if i=0 generate
                    FF1: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => int_0,
                            crc => crc_t(i), --funziona benissimo se metto dout(i)
                            q   => q_s(i)
                            );

                end generate FIRST; 

            THIRD: if i=2 generate
                    FF2: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => int_2,
                            crc => crc_t(i),
                            q   => q_s(i)
                                );
                end generate THIRD;

            FIFTH: if i=4 generate
                    FF4: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => int_4,
                            crc => crc_t(i),
                            q   => q_s(i)
                                );
                end generate FIFTH;


            INTERNAL: if i>0 and i<Nbit-1 and i/= 2 and i/=4 generate
                    FFI: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => q_s(i-1),
                            crc => crc_t(i),
                            q   => q_s(i)
                                );
                end generate INTERNAL;

            LAST:    if i=Nbit-1 generate
                    FFN: DFC port map (
                            clk     => clk,
                            reset   => reset,
                            d   => q_s(i-1),
                            crc => crc_t(i),
                            q   => q_s(i)
                            );
                end generate LAST;
    end generate GEN;


    variable t : natural := 0;

    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            t:= t+1;
            if t=24 then 
                dout <= crc_t;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end rtl;
```

Of course on line 35, where I put "d    => din xor q_s(Nbit-1)", the compiler gives me an error. How can I obtain the result I want to get?

I tried putting intermediary signal to pass this problem, but I can't understand why this is not working as expected.

This is the code of the DFC component:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity DFC is 
    port(
        clk :in std_logic;
        reset   :in std_logic;
        d   :in std_logic;
        crc :out    std_logic;
        q   :out    std_logic
    );  
end DFC;

architecture rtl of DFC is
    begin
        process(clk, reset, d)
        begin
            if(reset = '1')then
                q <= '0';
                crc<= '0';
            elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then
                q <= d;
                crc <= d;
            end if;
        end process;
end rtl;
```

Thanks all for the aswers.
Gabriele.

Edit: I added all the LFSR code and the DFC code.

Comment: I think I can't understand you well. But, continuing working on the code, I tried to use intermediaries signals,  the compiler goes, but now the flipflops are never initialized. I put the code segment for clarity

Comment: If your question were to consist of a [mcve] based on the second code snippet after fixing the original problem it would analyze and provide a specific problem when simulated. *but I can't understand why this is not working as expected* does not provide a specific problem nor can the problem be reproduced without a testbench or known stimuli being applied with expected and actual results. You're asking someone to guess. You can also remove the first code snippet, it doesn't provide a problem not already found in other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is incomplete because it does not have a [minimal reproductible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other word, it is hard to help you.

**Prior to VHDL-2008:**
You cannot perform such action : `d => din xor q_s(Nbit-1)` because this line is seen as an operation and that is not possible in an instantiation of an entity or a component.

(like in this post for example: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/184893/warning-actual-for-formal-port-a-is-neither-a-static-name-nor-a-globally-stati)

However, there is a way to work around that, you have to create a new signal

Notice that when you use your code, the error should be something like: `Actual for formal port a is neither a static name nor a globally static expression`

**With VHDL-2008:**

If look in the norm: http://www.fis.agh.edu.pl/~skoczen/hdl/ieee_std/ieee1076-2008.pdf
You can find on paragraph 6.5.6.3 Port clauses:

> If a formal port of mode in is associated with an expression that is not globally static (see 9.4.1) and the
>   formal is of an unconstrained or partially constrained composite type requiring determination of index
>   ranges from the actual according to the rules of 5.3.2.2, then the expression shall be one of the following:
>
> - The name of an object whose subtype is globally static
> - An indexed name whose prefix is one of the members of this list
> - A slice name whose prefix is one of the members of this list and whose discrete range is a globally static discrete range
> - An aggregate, provided all choices are locally static and all expressions in element associations are expressions described in this list
> - A function call whose return type mark denotes a globally static subtype
> - A qualified expression or type conversion whose type mark denotes a globally static subtype
> - An expression described in this list and enclosed in parentheses

In other word, in VHDL-2008, the code you provided should work.

About your initialization problem, it is unclear, what signals/varibles are not initialized ? The best you can do is, if your first question is well answered by this post, then accept it has a solution or edit your question for more clarity. Then ask an other question in an other thread about the initialization problem. You can also post your question on [Electronics Stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It was simple after all. I'm new to VHDL so I'm continuing doing stupid errors.

Comment: No problem, best of luck for your projects